# Geocouch Query Error

Tags: nosql, couchdb, couchbase

I am running Couchbase Single Server 1.2 and attempting to use the Geospatial indexing features (GeoCouch).
I have followed all the instructions in the readme. My design document is structured as follows:

```
{ _id: "_design/main",
 _rev: "24-4bfa80ed0a93b7bff3008a64a4b0ff89",
 language: "javascript",
 spatial: {
            points: "function(doc) {
                          if (doc.loc) {
                                 emit({ \"type\": \"Point\", \"coordinates\": doc.loc }, [doc._id, doc.loc]);
                           }
                     };"
          }
}
```

My couchdb database is called places. When places is empty, if I call the bounding box query,
http://localhost:5984/places/_design/main/_spatial/points?bbox=0,0,180,90
I get the following:

```
{
      rows: [ ]
}
```

It looks good. It means the query url is working correctly.

But when I add some data to the places database, such as the following:

```
{
    _id: "berlin",
    _rev: "1-204646602c35d80238ad345ca8d3fcef",
    loc:
        [
            -122.270833,
            37.804444
        ]
}
```

and call the bounding box query again, I get the following error:

```
{
error: "{{badmatch,{ok,8497}}, [{vtree_bulk,omt_write_tree,4}, {vtree_bulk,omt_write_tree,2}, {vtree_bulk,bulk_load,4}, {vtree,add_remove,5}, {couch_spatial_updater,'-write_changes/4-fun-2-',5}, {lists,zipwith,3}, {couch_spatial_updater,write_changes,4}, {couch_spatial_updater,update,2}]}",
reason: "{gen_server,call,[<0.22235.0>,{request_group,41},infinity]}"
}
```

I am running Couchbase 1.2 on a Windows 7 (32-bit) development machine.

Does anyone have any idea about this error?

Thanks.

Comment: The design document above has some nested quote issues as displayed here, but I'm assuming the strings within your points function source code are correctly escaped in practice?

Comment: Looks like this might be the same problem as here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927022/geocouch-query-badmatch-error

Comment: the strings were properly escaped in the function source code. However, I have edited my original posting to reflect the escapes...just for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried it on Linux with Couchbase Single Server 1.2 and couldn't reproduce it. Could you please try the latest deveoper preview of Couchbase Single Server 2.0. You can get it [here](http://files.couchbase.com/developer-previews/couchbase-single-server-2.0.0-dev-preview/).

Comment: ok so I tried the latest developer preview of couchbase single server 2.0 preview 5 and it works. But it would be great to find out what the problem was with version 1.2. Specifically on windows 7. Thanks :)